# Someone who buys and sells apartments, houses and foreign exchange

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, word-meaning, difference

I was wondering what would you call a person who buys and sales **houses and apartments"** and **"foreign exchange and currencies"**?
Actually, I know several terms, but I have no idea how they differ in meaning and what is the common one for each case?

For houses and apartments buy and sales:

> **a.** real estate dealer 
>   **b.** real estate broker

For currency and foreign exchange buy and sales (in this specific case, I'm not about the official agencies who are dealing with these affairs; but rather I am about those people who are dealing with buying and selling foreign currencies in black market.)

> **a.** money dealer 
>   **b.** money broker 
>   **c.** currency dealer 
>   **d.** currency broker 
>   **e.** foreign exchange dealer 
>   **f.** foreign exchange broker

Answer (score 2):

A "broker" or an "agent" is someone who organises buying and selling on behalf of someone else.

So, if I want to sell my house, I will talk to an *estate agent*.  If I want to to sell stocks and shares in a company, I'll get a *stockbroker*. A dealer is someone who is buying or selling with their own money. A car dealer, for example, is buying and selling cars.

A foreign exchange broker (forex broker) works in a financial centre like the City of London. They do trades in currency for worth millions of pounds for large companies. You don't go to a forex broker to buy €500 for a holiday. You would go to a foreign currency exchange, usually at a bank or post office. There are specialist foreign currency exchanges at airports etc. I suppose you could call the person who works here a *currency dealer*. Terms like "money dealer" put me in mind of an unlicenced guy, selling dollars on a street corner.

Comment: Does it mean that the owner of a private foreign currency exchange office and his/her staff are called **"currency dealers"** and those who are unlicenced and illegal who are working on streets corners are called **"money dealers"** @James K?

Comment: Also, I wonder what would you call someone who buys a house and sells it in profit with their own money? @James K, as you mentioned, it should be a "dealer", but a dealer **of what**? **"House dealer"** or a **"real estate dealer"** or a **house market dealer"** or an **apartment dealer"** etc.?

Comment: I already mentioned that.  That person is a "developer" or a "real estate developer".

Comment: A real estate developer would be someone who builds or terraforms on a plot of land; developing the real estate into something else. Someone who simply buys and sells real estate (a might renovate) is usually referred to as a real estate investor. If they do it rapidly (buying, renovating, and then selling in often 60 days or less), they would also be known as house flippers.